# Accumulator Design

Tags: vhdl

Thank you, everyone, here I have modified the post. I have written a simple code VHDL for trap filter by using different components for each task. The below is sample code where different components are used and all the other components are working perfectly except accumulator component(acc1), the out signal remains zero. In the acc1 one component I am trying to to make two accumulators where the first acc1 (output of the first accumulator) is the input for the acc2. As the other components are working so here I only showed the port mapping of acc1 component in the code along the test bench.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;
ENTITY TRAPFILTER IS 
GENERIC (
K  : integer  :=80;
L  : integer  :=200
 --M  : signed(9 downto 0)  := to_signed(5)
);
PORT 
(
 CLK          : IN    STD_LOGIC;
 RST          : IN    STD_LOGIC; 
 DATAIN       : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 DOWNTO 0);
 DATAOUT      : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(24 DOWNTO 0);
 DATAOUT1     : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(25 DOWNTO 0); ---
 READY        : OUT   STD_LOGIC;

 Soutout      : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
 Koutout      : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
 Loutout      : out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0)
 ); 
 END ENTITY TRAPFILTER;
 ARCHITECTURE RTL OF TRAPFILTER IS
   constant M          : sfixed(1 downto -2) :=  to_sfixed(0.01,1,-2); 
   type  Sdelay_reg is array(0 to 2) OF signed(21 downto 0);
   signal S_reg        :  Sdelay_reg :=(others=>(others=>'0'));
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   signal y_reg0       : signed (27 downto 0)  :=(others=>'0'); 
   signal y_reg1       : signed (31 downto 0)  :=(others=>'0');        
   -----------------------------------------------------------
    signal in_reg      : signed(13 downto 0)  :=(others=>'0');
    signal out_reg     : signed(DATAOUT'length-1 downto 0)  := 
     (others=>'0');
     -- ----------------------------------------------------------
     signal fs          : std_logic :='0';
    --------------------kdelay component----------------------------------
    component kdelay is 
        GENERIC (
        K  : integer  :=80;
        L  : integer  :=200
        );
         port 
          (
              clk           : in  std_logic ;
              rst           : in  std_logic;
              din           : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (13 downto 0);
              kout          : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (13 downto 0)

                   );
                end component;
                signal kout   : std_logic_vector (13 downto 0) :=(others=> 
                '0');
                --------------------Ldelay component---------------------- 
                ------------
              component Ldelay is 
               GENERIC (
                    K  : integer  :=80;
                    L  : integer  :=200

                    );
                 port 
                         (
                          clk          : in  std_logic ;
                         rst           : in  std_logic;
                         din           : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (13 downto 
                                           0);
                         Lout          : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (13 downto 
                                             0)

                      );
                       end component;
                      signal Lout : std_logic_vector (13 downto 0) := 
                      (others=>'0');
                       ---------------------------------------------------
                      component sub_mult is 
                      port(
                            clk           : in  std_logic ;
                            rst           : in  std_logic;
                            din           : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (13 downto 
                                             0);
                            Sout          : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 
                                            downto 0)
                                       );
                              end component;
                               signal Sout    : std_logic_vector (23 
                                              downto 0) :=(others=>'0');     
                               -------------------------------------------
                                component accum1 is 
                                     port(
                                         clk           : in  std_logic ;
                                         rst           : in  std_logic;
                                         din           : in 
                                         STD_LOGIC_VECTOR  (23 downto 0);
                                         Acout          : out 
                                         STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (24 downto 0);
                                         Acout1         : out 
                                         STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (25 downto 0)
                                            );
                                            end component;
                                          signal acc_out1 : std_logic_vector (24 downto 0) :=(others=>'0');
                                         signal acc_out2 : std_logic_vector (25 downto 0) :=(others=>'0');
                                          ----------------------------------------------------------------
                     BEGIN
                       Koutout     <= Kout;
                       Loutout     <= Lout;
                       Soutout     <= Sout;
                       in_reg      <= signed (DATAIN);
                       DATAOUT     <= acc_out1;--std_logic_vector(out_reg);
                      DATAOUT1    <= acc_out2;
                      utacc1:component accum1  
                      port map(
                          clk           => clk,
                          rst           => rst,--: in  std_logic;
                         din           => Sout, --: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR 
              (13 downto 0);
                       Acout         => acc_out1, -- : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (24 downto 0)
                      Acout1        => acc_out2
                      );
                     END RTL;
                  ------------------------Accum1 component----------------------------------
  library IEEEieee;`
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;

   entity accum1 is port(
clk           : in  std_logic ;
rst           : in  std_logic;
din           : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR  (23 downto 0);
Acout          : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (24 downto 0);
Acout1         : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (25 downto 0)
 ); 
end entity;
architecture rtl of accum1 is
signal dout        :  signed(24 downto 0) :=(others=>'0');    
signal datain      : signed(23 downto 0) :=(others=>'0');
signal dout2       : signed(25 downto 0)  :=(others=>'0');
begin
datain        <= signed(din);
process(clk,rst,datain)
variable cm     : signed(24 downto 0);
begin
       if(rst='1' ) then
          dout    <= (others=>'0'); 
          dout2    <= (others=>'0');
          cm     := (others=>'0');
        elsif(rising_edge(clk) and clk'event) then    
            cm    := datain + cm;
            dout  <= cm ;
            dout2 <= dout2 + cm ;
        end if;
        end process;
    Acout        <= std_logic_vector(dout);
   Acout1      <= std_logic_vector(dout2) ; 
  end rtl;
  ------------------------test bench only trapfilter comppnent portmapping
              uttrap5:component TRAPFILTER  
              PORT MAP
              (
               CLK        => TestClk, --        : IN    STD_LOGIC;
               RST        => i_rstb, --  : IN    STD_LOGIC; 
               DATAIN     => odata, --odata, -- : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 DOWNTO 0);
              DATAOUT     => trap_out, --: OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(13 DOWNTO 0); ---
              DATAOUT1    => trap_out1,
              READY       => trap_ready,  --: OUT   STD_LOGIC
              Koutout     => Koutout, --out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
              Loutout      => loutout, --: out std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
              Soutout     => Soutout

           );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwoGf.jpg)

Comment: Please post a full MCVE. Your waveform doesnt match the code. And its not clear what problem you are asking about. The uninitialised signal in the waveform doesnt appear to exist in the code.

Comment: The simulation waveform shows a 14 element signal purportedly as a 24 element input, doesn't show `clk` or `rst`, the only unknown signal is a ready. `trap_out1` is all '0's. Four errors in the first two code lines (back ticks are not legal in VHDL, the reserved word `use` is never preceded by an apostrophe, the library logical name `ieeeIEEE` is incorrect), `and clk'event` not needed in the condition, the last two use clauses aren't used. Without a testbench maybe reset is always asserted or there is no clock. Please provide a [mcve] for something other than guesses.

Comment: 1) There are still 2 errors on the first line of the `accum1`. 2) With the commented changes and a rudimentary testbench accum1 [simulates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8noU.jpg). 3) You don't provide a [mcve], there's no testbench for trapfilter nor accum1. 4) without Sout being driven (no instantiation of sub_mult) the actual for  `utacc1:component accum1`port formal `din` is all '0's (`signal Sout:     std_logic_vector (23 downto 0) :=(others=>'0');`). 5) You don't use Synopsys package std_logic_unsigned in any shown code. Creating a **minimal** reproducible example can point to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues in your code

1. You don't need `datain` in your sensitivity list.
2. When using `rising_edge`, you don't need `event`
3. The variable `cm` will not keep their value when re-enter the process. Use `signal` instead or just use value of `dout`.
4. I am really understand what is your `dout2` logic?

Comment: A process statement's declarative part is statically elaborated and variable `cm` will retain it's value between the time the process is suspended and resumes unlike dynamically elaborated subprogram calls. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.5.5 Other concurrent statements, 14.6 Dynamic elaboration, 14.4 Elaboration of a declarative part. Simulation with a testbench would demonstrated the variable `cm` holds it's value. Also see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)